# What's the difference between gunzip and unzip?

Tags: compression, zip

What is the difference between gunzip and unzip? Tried to search but couldn't find anything relevant with this.

Comment: There was no need to search something. All you had to do just to open `man unzip` and then open `man gunzip`. All differences are there. ;)

Comment: Or for a concise one-line description, `whatis gunzip unzip`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

unzip decompress `zip` algorithm same `*.zip files` and gunzip decompress  `gz` algorithm that same `*.gz files`.
If you migrated from windows, You have many compression algorithm in UNIX world such as   *.7z , *.gz , *.bz2 and so on. Also you can compress file which already archived with tar command:
such as :

```
tar -zcvf mydir.tar.gz mydir #gz and tar
tar -jcvf mydir.tar.bz2 mydir #bz2 and tar 
tar -Jcvf mydir.tar.xz mydir #xz and tar
```

Comment: tar -Jcvf mydir.tar.xz mydir #xz and tar

Comment: tar --use-compress-program=funky-compress cvf mydir.tar.fc mydir #Some other compression

Comment: Why do you say that 7z is "a compression algorithm in UNIX world"?

Answer (score 10):

They are two different programs to unzip two different types of compressed files:

- **unzip**: "*list, test and extract compressed files in a ZIP archive*" (from the man page). The Zip file format is the most commonly used compression format on Windows machines, the file ending is typically `.zip`.  See the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29]) for more information.
- **gunzip**: For a similar file format for single compressed files, much more common in Unix/Linux systems.  The file ending is typically `.gz`. *gzip* files contain only one compressed file, if compression of a folder-like structure is required, additional tools like `tar` are used, typically resulting in compressed folders with a line ending `.tar.gz` or `.tgz`.  [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) is what Wikipedia has to say about the *gzip* format and program.